# gnome-control-center does not open after Fedora upgrade

Tags: fedora, gnome, sway

I upgraded my Fedora on two different systems from Fedora 36 resp. 37 to 38. I use sway but like to use gnome-control-center for having a settings GUI. Before the upgrade this worked fine, but after the upgrade nothing happens if I try to open it.

Executing `gnome-control-center` on the terminal doesn't do anything and the journal does not print any error. I even reinstalled gnome-shell and gnome-control-center, but nothing changed. Also if I use gnome for the session, there is only a loading mouse icon, but the settings do not open up.

Is there any log, where I could look for some kind for error log or anything else?